# Why does my 2nd tab automatically assign a tabIndex of -1

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

```
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="Tab0" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="true">
    <a href="#Tab0" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">
        <span class="titlecase">jones,mike dr</span>
    </a>
</li>
<li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="Tab1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false">
    <a href="#Tab1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">
        <span class="titlecase">asdf,asdfasd mrs</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

I have a function that will change the tab on the index its on, but for some reason it automatically gets `-1` for the second so my `onclick="javascript:ChangeTabLocation('1');"` never hits the second tab.

Any ideas where in the code it automatically assigns a `-1` to that?

Comment: What generates the HTML for the tabs or what code are you running that interacts with the tabs? It seems all of your tab index values for the tabs as well as the anchors is set to `-1` after the first one. Maybe something wrong with how the HTML is generated or something wrong with the code which interacts with it. Not enough information in this question I think.

Comment: What is this function javascript:ChangeTabLocation('1') have inside of it? You are passing in a hard coded variable to it.

Comment: Its inside a repeater so e.Item.ItemIndex + 1) or e.Item.ItemIndex - 1)

Comment: why aren't you using the jQueryUI tabs API to switch tabs?

Comment: Its old code that I am thinking about replacing but it did use some of what I have read on the UI api.  $tabs.tabs('select', tabIndex); That is what I wasnt sure of either, so I tried $tabs.tabs('option', 'active', tabIndex); but that didnt work either

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net, no reason `tabs('select', tabIndex)` should not work